# How much support does something need to be policy?

Tags: discussion, policy, meta

Of fortunately, there is no metametacodegolf, so I will just put my question here. At https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22646/16842, someone said my question violated a post here, but the post had less than 25 votes. So my question is, how much support does something need to become policy?

Comment: To be honest, I was surprised that there are more than 10 people who visit meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On top of these two fine answers which I have upvoted, I will add:

#### No one needs a policy to downvote you; they only need an opinion.

Policy or not, each user is free to vote as they see fit. So the "policy" is not so much a real policy 'graved in stone, but a set of principles - a way of thinking about the kind of community we want to be.

If someone invokes that way of thinking when they downvote you, they are probably doing so as a courtesy so you know *why* you were downvoted. It's actually pretty nice, because it sucks getting downvoted with no comment.

But no amount of disputing the policy they invoke - even if successfully - is going to diminish their right to downvote you anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Oh, *only* less than 25? You do realize it's the **fifth highest** voted meta post, and it's only been around for less than two weeks? Is an almost record-breaking amount of votes not support enough?

Here on Stack Exchange, the *community* runs the site. The obvious consensus is that it's a good idea, and **we, as a community,** are enforcing it.

Answer (score 8):

To support Doorknob's post, that policy now has 20 upvotes (the 20th being mine). That means there are 20 more supporters than dissenters. Given the size of this community that has a vocal opinion about policy, I'd say a 20-point lead is a pretty clear show of support. Heck, even a 10-point lead would lend significant weight, in my opinion.

Speaking for myself, if hardcoding were decided to be okay on this site, I'd quit. I find the idea to be offensive, and usually I nuke such "answers" on sight.